# Is there a way for a dependency service to specify its own lifetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I would like for a service to be able to specify its own lifetime so as to prevent accidental misuse of the service. Is there a way to do this? Alternatively, is there a way for a service to determine at creation time what its lifetime is?

Comment: The lifetime of an object is not determined by itself, but by who creates it, who stores references to it and ultimately who uses it. All these things are external to a class.

Comment: The simple answer is-- don't inject the service itself. Inject a factory that can be used to obtain an instance of the service. Since you control the code in the factory, you can control whether the same instance or a different instance is returned each time.

Comment: @JohnWu, I think that may be the best approach.

Comment: @Alejandro, I'm aware of that. However, some services don't work well with certain lifetimes. I have such a case, and I simply want to prevent developers from coming along later and misusing the service.